# cmake: execute a command after subdirectories files are built

Tags: cmake, build

I have the following structure:

```
main direcotry
            |
            --> subdirecotry1
            --> subdirectory2
                 | 
                 --> subdirecotry21
                 --> subdirecotry22
                 --> subdirecotry23
                 --> subdirecotry24
                 ...
```

in the main cmake I have:

```
add_subdirectory("subdirecotry1")
add_subdirectory("subdirecotry2")
```

and I have command to be executed after all subdirectories are built using:

```
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT  ${OUTPUT}
        DEPNEDS subdirecotry1/ouptput.exe subdirecotry2/subdirecotry21/ouptput.exe subdirecotry2/subdirecotry22/ouptput.exe ...
        COMMAND ---some command here---
)
```

Since I have too many small files generated in the subdirectories of subdirectory2, is there way to avoid stating all files in DEPNEDS and just say dependency on all files in that subdirectory ?

Comment: The documentation for [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) suggests that `MAIN_DEPENDENCY` only accepts one dependency, not a list. You could instead provide a list of dependencies to the `DEPENDS` argument, a list that could be populated as you traverse `subdirectory2`, appending new `output.exe` files to the list as you go. FWIW, if `output.exe` is a CMake target, I think you can simply specify the CMake target name, instead of the full path to the executable.

Comment: my bad, I meant `DEPENDS` not `MAIN_DEPENDENCY`. Is there any way to specify the dependency on the subdirectory as whole (including its output executables) instead of specifying individual executables

Comment: `add_custom_command` won't even run in your example.  A target needs to use the output of `add_custom_command` for it to be included in the build process, otherwise it is ignored.

Comment: yeah, I have `add_custom_target(compile ALL DEPENDS ${OUTPUT})` which runs add_custom_command.